# What Am I missing in proper understanding of daily rep cap?

Tags: support, reputation, daily-reputation-limit

Reference: If required, my [reputation tab link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2173917/sourav-ghosh?tab=reputation).

- Daily Rep cap: 200
- Exception: Accpeted answers and Bounties.

Today, I have 4 accepted answers. `(4 *15) == 60`. So, my all total possible maximium rep for today can be 260.

I'm seeing a cap on 250, as the upvotes after that don't give me any rep.

Worthy to mention, earlier today, I lost 12 reputation due to unupvote on some old answers.

So, I get a feeling that the rep points which were deducted earlier today, is *added* for the calculation of daily cap, which is obviously, very weird. Rather I was hoping, I need to have 272 to hit the daily cap while compensating for the deducted points.

Please help me in understanding the scenario (or rather, clear my misunderstanding).

Comment: I suggest you have a look at what http://stackoverflow.com/reputation shows for today. I suspect it will show 260, and it just won't show the reputation *increases* for the now-removed upvotes.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165679/rep-cap-and-user-removed <- Applies to all removal events including unupvotes.

Comment: OMG !! Did i just get a comment from Mr. @JonSkeet himself for my question? Big day for me. :-)

Comment: @Mysticial Thanks sir, I think I understand now.

Comment: Just to inform all, [reputaton](http://stackoverflow.com/reputation) shows 260. Thanks to @JonSkeet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an answer is unupvoted it shows up n the reputation tab for today, because that's when you lost the rep, but as far as the rep cap is concerned it isn't happening today at all; it's as if the upvote was never cast in the first place.  So if, on the day that the removed upvote was added, you were over the cap by an upvote, you wouldn't have lost rep at all.  And since the -10 rep doesn't affect today's rep cap, it doesn't allow an extra upvote beyond the cap *today* to compensate.