# Shouldn't voting correction be reflected by the daily rep cap?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, voting-correction

Some 12 hours ago someone went on an upvoting spree, well exceeding the daily rep cap. That has been quickly addressed and corrected a couple of hours later.

But a while ago I noticed that a recent upvote was not reflected, presumably because I have "hit the limit" with practically **zero** daily rep. That happened over 10 hours after the voting was corrected, meaning that the daily cap is a one time trigger rather than a persistent check.

Wouldn't it make more sense if the voting correction was reflected by the daily cap? It seems like that scenario was overlooked. Especially in light of [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295847/991484), which states that in the event of an un-upvote:

> it's as if the upvote was never cast in the first place

So it would make sense to see the same behavior for voting corrections, which is essentially a "system" un-upvote.

Comment: it's always nice to know you have some friends out there :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre more like stalkers really :)

Comment: I'm glad it never happened to me. Only got haters who serially downvoted me.

Comment: I had a colleague who did that *twice*, even after I *explicitly* told him not to after the first time. It was a rather sad story having a "devotee", to the point of ordering the same food in the lunch break and buying the same clothes and even computer parts... This one is rather extreme thou... looking at the logs, the upvotes are literally few seconds apart.

Comment: I am the one who caused this mess and I would like to use the opportunity to officially and deeply apologize. I didn't want to do any harm, though it turned out that I actually did. I've tried to bring more positivity, but obviously in the wrong way. Anyway, I am aware now it shouldn't be done this way, so I will have that in mind in the future. Sorry for the troubles!

Comment: No good deed goes unpunished ;) Don't sweat it, now you know. And besides it did help uncover a bug that nobody seems to want to fix.

Comment: :) you are right about the bug of course. But speaking about the case, the funny thing is that I actually planned to do such "favor" (I thought it is a favor) to a bunch of people here, who I think deserve my up votes because they have either helped me directly by answering my questions or indirectly by providing answers to someone else, which was also helpful to me. Good that the things were clarified before my positiveness were spread in a rapid and devastating way. :) Yes, now I know.

Comment: Tagging this as [status-bydesign] not for the fact the bug happens (it's a behavior we can only spend so much CPU on), but the fact that it's self-correcting and ultimately no rep is lost.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The daily cap takes vote reversals into account, and there is no need to worry.

The [reputation log in your profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991484/dtech?tab=reputation) includes 'historical' events, those that no longer actually count (like those from automatic corrections), but the cap is applied on each full re-calculation. Such recalcs happen quite regularly, like a post is deleted or a vote reversal has taken place.

This process is failing to account for the (rare) occasion that you hit the rep cap before the 3am automatic serial vote reversal, so until the next UTC day, your reputation will be reported as capped; once a new reputation cycle starts a recalculation will correct for the error.

As such, your *actual* reputation is not affected, and you'll still gain +10 points until you reach the cap *after* the reversal has been accounted for.

You can always audit your reputation at https://stackoverflow.com/reputation, it'll show you got points for those most recent upvotes.

Comment: It seems it has already been accounted for, but I don't get any rep for the 2 upvotes from today, only for an answer accept. And I am not *worried* about it, it just seems like a bug. It seems that after receiving 20 upvotes, any subsequent upvotes receive no rep even after all the upvotes that triggered the cap have been removed.

Comment: @dtech: it'll certainly be corrected for tomorrow. You can trigger an update with the delete of a post (and you can undelete it a little while later).

Comment: Yes that "text thing" does show it correctly. So it seems that the bug is in the GUI not in the rep tracking, as it still doesn't show it correctly.

Comment: @dtech Votes that get reversed on the same day are bugged while "the same day = today" because of how we keep track of the rep cap for today. It will fix itself every time you're eligible for a recalc, but keep thinking you're still rep capped. Once tomorrow hits, another recalc will correct the day for good.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, I presumed, evidently incorrectly, that having a GUI that doesn't properly reflect the underlying data is a bug, little did I know that's how you do it ;)

Comment: @dtech It *is* a bug, just not a very high priority one given that there's only a 3 hour window each day where this issue can present itself (given automatic invalidations are only performed at 03:00 UTC every day) and that the system will fix itself eventually. Trying to fix it has very little value to us.

Comment: Didn't know that seocnd link, interesting... But it says I reached the rep cap on 52 days, while my profile page says it's been 54 days (at the "legendary" badge tracker).

Comment: @RenéVogt the audit only looks at your currently active votes (so discounting deleted posts).  The badge probably counts days you reached 200 points without accounting for later vote recalculations.